# Nepali Date to English Date: Subtract - 56 Years - 8 Months - 16 Days

Tags: ms-access, vb6

English Date to Nepali Date: Add - 56 Years - 8 Months - 16 Days
Nepali Date to English Date: Subtract - 56 Years - 8 Months - 16 Days in vb6.0

I want to subtract date and add date to convert date from English to Nepali and Nepali to English I'm using following code but it converts only year because it is last line.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Text1.Text = Date
Text2.Text = DateAdd("d", 16, Text1.Text)
Text2.Text = DateAdd("m", 8, Text1.Text)
Text2.Text = DateAdd("yyyy", 56, Text1.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: I am very surprised that you can run this in VBA. The text property is only available to a control that has focus.

Comment: This is not a answer of my question! please tell me how to get a output of converted date by subtracting above content in text2.text

Comment: When I correct the code to `Me.Text2 = DateAdd("d", 16, Me.Text2)` and so on, it works in VBA. No, this is not an answer, it is a comment.

Comment: I think you will get in more Troubles, you have still an gregorian date, only changed by 56,7 years ... but the months (1..12) still have our gregorian length: 31,28/29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31. With some date, you will get an 31st in 12th month (our december, your chaitra), but chaitra has only 30 - you will not get the 1st baishak (what would be correct). you will have to write your own calender logic.

Comment: @ThomasKrojer You have a very good argument for a calendar table. BTW I think .net supports Nepali calendars.

Comment: Thank You so much but i get error with this code pls give me full code for it . I will be great help to me.

Comment: @Fionnuala: There is an EastAsianLunisolarCalendar in .NET - I´ve no idea if this is what you mean.

Comment: @rahul sikhwal: pleas show us the ACTUAL code and the error message. Only 'I get error' ist too less Information.

Comment: @ThomasKrojer calendar table : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22776.t-sql-calendar-table.aspx I know this is t-sql, but not so difficult to adopt to MS Access.

Comment: @Fionnuala - ist for Rahul, not for me. I don´t have to deal with non gregorian Dates. And Rahul is working with Access, not DotNet. If I would be in Rahuls situation, I would try to avoid a table by any means, I would try it with code (@Rahul: don´t forget the leap years!)

Comment: @ThomasKrojer u r right it doesn't work on the month of chaitra so this way adddate function doest work I think I have to address seperate table in  database in one row AD and in one row BS so can u help me by providing such a calender database so that it can be converted easily. Make sure I am using vb6.0 not .net

Comment: @Fionnuala thank u so much for your valuable comment but I am freaking out can't do it with codes as there are variations on month so by adding days months and years it can't work.

Comment: It CAN work: First: you take your date and calculate the Julian Day. Then add/substract whatever. Then calculate your Date from Julian Day. Just so as VB6 does this. Wiki tells you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

Comment: @ThomasKrojer If you know that much then please provide me a code also by calculate from my date from from julian today is 2071//11/08 (YYYY/MM/DD)

Comment: "simple" Version - 365 * 2071 + ( DAYOFYEAR ) = days in baisahk + days in .....  DONT FORGET YOUR LEAP YEARS .... AND GO TO WIKI AND SEE AN EXAMPLE HOW IT WORKS .... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

Comment: A calendar table has many uses, not just this. @ThomasKrojer code is not always the answer, there have been big debates about this before. In particular, code may not be the answer with the Nepali calendar, because the months are not easily predictable.

Comment: ok, if they are NOT calculatable, then you have to use a table. But if you are producing the table, you do this not by hand, but by code, so you will have to write a class (or a tittle tool) to fill the table.

Comment: @Fionnuala thats absolutely true.

Comment: I found an article here: http://codeissue.com/articles/a04e050dea7468f/algorithm-to-convert-english-date-to-nepali-date-using-c-net it´s c# but the logic is clear

Comment: @ThomasKrojer then could you please convert this logic and code into vb6.0?? So that it can be converted from code only as you say from vb6.0?

Comment: @Fionnuala and I will be clear from your code provided through vb6.0 script isn't

Comment: sorry, I will not code anything. I give hints, ok, but vor coding vb6 I have to visit my old office where I have an old pc with vb6 installed. Thats an hour only to travel there.

Comment: I add an answer, But If you want to subtract you need to use negative values ;).

Answer (score 0):

As you say `I want to subtract ...` :

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Text1.Text = Date
    Text2.Text = DateAdd("d", -16, Text1.Text)
    Text2.Text = DateAdd("m", -8, Text2.Text)
    Text2.Text = DateAdd("yyyy", -56, Text2.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: I think your problem in this code actually is using `Text1` => `Text2` ;).