# How to determine the number of days in a month based on Hindu Calender(Vikram Sambat)?

Tags: date

My client wants to work in Nepal's Official Calendar- Hindu Calendar (Vikram Sambat). Currently i am using JQuery Ui selector which is static one. In application I need to find the number of days between two dates which are in `Vikram Sambat Format`; Now, I need to convert Nepali date to English and find the number of days.

> And most awkward thing is, general convention of converting date 
>   algorithm could not work perfectly for too old dates like 1960's and
>   upcoming dates.

By tallying I found that with in 60 years there were only 14 leap years in Vikram Sambat format, actually there must 15 leap years according english date, and number of days in a month also  varying year to year some time having 31 some time 32.

I don't want to make use of array for this purpose, i want to know the logic that could determine the number of days in a month.

One of the general convention is [Nepali Date to English Date: Subtract - 56 Years - 8 Months - 16 Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002850/nepali-date-to-english-date-subtract-56-years-8-months-16-days)

Comment: looking for the answer myself..

Comment: I'm also in quest of same solution; let's hope we'll get one soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a open source `NepDate` class library on .NET

Please see the documentation here : https://github.com/TheCrossLegCoder/NepDate/blob/main/README.md

It has a property `MonthEndDay` which will represent the no of days in the particular month.

GitHub: https://github.com/TheCrossLegCoder/NepDate

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NepDate